# Solr - Filter query functions on inconsistent field

Tags: php, solr, pecl

I am currently working on a project with a Solr (6.4.0) installation and struggling to get my head around a query, which I believe I need to use  a query function to meet my requirements.

My application has one Solr core which spans across 5 different document types (users can index websites, documents, articles etc). The problem I have is that articles have start and end dates so a user may create an article in advance and set a start date of 2 weeks from now. When querying Solr I want to add a function that will explicitly ignore all index-type:article where active date is greater than now, however not exclude other document types like websites etc.

I have been reading up on a Solr Wiki page [(https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#if)](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#if) where it has some good examples however I think I may be implementing wrong as I am not seeing the desired results. I am using the [PECL PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) extension and and adding the query like so:

```
$query->addFilterQuery("if(exists(active-date), active-date:[* TO NOW], 1)");
```

If I perform a `*:*` search around 900 results are returned and the index has circa 8000 records where only 2 article's have active dates that are in the future and the total count of all "articles" is around 200 so it seems to be filtering out of of other "index-types" instead of returning 1 (positive number == true) on the else value.

**In summary**, I need a query that will look for the field "active-date" (which is only configured on index-type:article), check if the date is in the future - if true then exclude, if false include in result set and if field not present include in result set.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you'd actually need a function query:

```
fq=(index-type:article AND active-date:[* TO NOW]) OR (*:* -active-date:*)
```

.. as long as the active-date field is present on all article objects. If it's not, you can add an extra condition to `OR` in any documents that doesn't have the field.

Comment: You're answer almost gave the desired results however the final OR needed tweaking. inline `$query->addFilterQuery("(index-type:article AND active-date:[* TO NOW]) OR (*:* -active-date:*)");` If you want to update your answer to the above code I will mark as answered so you get the cred because I wouldn't have found this without your help :)

Comment: Done. The old example was `*:* -index-type:article`, but since you don't have an active-date field on any other resource than those with `index-type:article`, your change works fine.